# Merging in an Array

Tags: arrays

If we have 2 integer arrays and we want to merge them into a third bigger array.

To do so we need to sort both the arrays before merging. I want to know that can we merge the 2 arrays first and than sort the third array created after merging?

Using this method we will require to sort only one array (The unsorted array created after merging). However if we sort the 2 arrays before merging, then while adding their elements to the third array we will have to sequentially compare elements of one sorted array with the other, so that the third array we get is also sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a performance benefit: Merging unsorted arrays is fine if you do not need to enforce a guarantee of no duplicate entries in the final array. However: The sort cost of an array is O(n log n). So, to abuse the terminology a bit, sorting both separately gives O(2*n log(n)). Sorting both together is O(2*n log(2*n)). That gap is where the extra necessary work of merging sorted arrays comes from.